# jQuery delay after click to "copy" text

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have a page where the user clicks a button ("generate") to dynamically generate a random phrase using text pulled from json file. The phrase is placed in a div (#generated) replacing what was previously there (before button clicked). Generating the phrase works perfectly. What I want to add now is a way for the user to click a tweet button to share that phrase.

Here's the tweet button code:

```
<div id="tweet_button">
<a href="http://twitter.com/share"
class="twitter-share-button"
data-text="This is what we want to change dynamically"
data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>
```

Plus this in the header:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

The `data-text` is what I'm looking to tweet using the content of the div after the button is pressed. Here's my problem:

First, if try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
$('a[data-text]').each(function(){
$(this).attr('data-text', $('#generated').text() );
});
});
```

then of course, the `data-text` changes from "This is what we want to change dynamically" to what was in the div before the "generate" button was pressed (i.e., what was there when the document was ready), which is not what I want. So, I figured I could use this code and `data-text` would change to the newly generated content of the div:

```
$("generate").click(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
$('a[data-text]').each(function(){
$(this).attr('data-text', $('#generated').text() );
});
},
1000);
});
```

In my mind, this would wait until the "generate" button was clicked, delay for a second (to ensure the div content changed) and then update the `data-text` with the new content of the div. Of course, this isn't working.

Ideally, the `data-text` would updated each time the "generate" button was clicked. Seems like there might be a way to do this (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/890) part, but for now I'm just worried about the first part as outlined above.

Hoping this makes sense...any idea how to actually do this? Thanks for the support of this complete rookie.

Comment: Why are you using $.getScript here? i don't get it

Comment: In hindsight, might not need that line since I have this full twitter script in the header, but do you think this is the issue? I removed that line and made no impact.

Comment: For sure, you should not load script twice but i don't think its your issue. In fact, i don't really understand your issue. You should wrap your click handler in document ready. Check if your click event is fired. But, from where is supposed to come the dynamic text, and how?

Comment: Dynamic text is generated using javascript when the "generate" button is clicked. That part works fine. What I want is for the tweet button to share this newly generated dynamic text. The dynamic text replaces the content of a div after you click the "generate" button. I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm very new to this and not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it like "regenerating" tweet button:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/xAq5t/

```
$("#generate").click(function () {
    $("#tweet_button").empty();
    $("#tweet_button").append('<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="' + $('#generated').text() + '" data-count="none">Tweet</a>');
    twttr.widgets.load();
});
```

Of course you should tweak it, because you use ajax functions to change text of "#generated"

**EDIT**

Maybe something like this

```
$("#generate").click(function () {
    $('#generated').load('data.txt', function () {
        $("#tweet_button").empty();
        $("#tweet_button").append('<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="' + $('#generated').text() + '" data-count="none">Tweet</a>');
        twttr.widgets.load();
    });
});
```

Comment: Text should change after clicking "generate".

Comment: I see now. It's working for me in the fiddle, but I can't get it to work in my page. Added call to get latest jquery ("jquery-latest.min.js"), but I'm obviously missing something. I see in the "Frameworks & Extensions" part of the fiddle, jquery is set to "onLoad". My version is obviously not doing this. How do I add that part to my own code to match the same action as the fiddle?

Comment: Should have tried on my own before asking. I got it. It's working! Thanks!